# java call method from parent on object from implemented class

Tags: java, parent, extends, implements

I am sure that this is an easy one. I have a java class called `vInteger`, which extends the class `Integer` (containing only `int` value, constructor, getter) and implements class `Comparing`. That one has an abstract method `compare(Comparing obj);` and I implemented it in the class `vInteger`. However, I can't call the getter from the `Integer` class to get the `int` value.
What is the problem here? :)

Thanks

Comment: Implements class????

Comment: Your class does not extend `java.lang.Integer`, because that class is marked as `final`.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: "I can't call the getter from the Integer class to get the int value" Why not? (And please don't answer "Because I get an error", but "Because I get an error which says XYZ".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to a custom `Integer` class (not a great idea, BTW, since it will hide `java.lang.Integer`, so it would be safer to rename it).

Now, you have a class that looks something like this (based on your description) :

```
public class vInteger extends Integer implements Comparing
{
    ...

    public int compare(Comparing obj)
    {
        // here you can access this.getIntValue() (the getter of your Integer class)
        // however, obj.getIntValue() wouldn't work, since `obj` can be of any
        // class that implements `Comparing`. It doesn't have to be a sub-class of
        // your Integer class. In order to access the int value of `obj`, you must
        // first test if it's actually an Integer and if so, cast it to Integer
        if (obj instanceof Integer) {
            Integer oint = (Integer) obj;
            // now you can do something with oint.getIntValue()
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

P.S., a better solution is to use a generic Comparing interface :

```
public interface Comparing<T>
{
    public int compare (T obj);
}

public class vInteger extends Integer implements Comparing<vInteger>
{
    public int compare (vInteger obj)
    {
        // now you can access obj.getIntValue() without any casting
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you see the Integer class then it's

```
public final class Integer  extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```

you cannot extend the class as it's final

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Mukesh Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5210128/mukesh-kumar).

And

Can you try following code ?

```
public class VInteger extends Number implements Comparable<Integer> {
```